# Linked list program won't remove object and is throwing a cast exception for unknown reason?

Tags: java, exception, linked-list

I am writing a basic linked list program. To test it I just created a basic *list*, added a bunch of things and then tried to remove them. It threw an *error* that I'm not understanding though.

The program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderedLinkedList one = new OrderedLinkedList();
    for(int i = 0; i<=20; i=i+2){
        one.add(i);
    }
    one.remove(3);
    //System.out.println(one.toString());

}
```

I wanted to see what would happen if I tried to remove an object that wasn't there. But when I did it threw this *exception*:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The *exception* seems to occur in my remove method in the line containing the `compareTo()` method. How am I trying to cast an int to a string? Shouldn't 3 be a comparable when it's passed to the method?

```
public boolean add(Comparable obj)
    {
        if(head.next == null){
        OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj, head, tail);
        }
        else{
            OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj,tail.previous,tail);
            tail.previous.next = newNode;
            tail.previous = newNode;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(Comparable obj)
    {
        OrderedListNode temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            if(temp.theItem.compareTo(obj) == 0){
                temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
/**
 *  Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
 */
public void clear()
{
    // reset header node
    head = new OrderedListNode("HEAD", null, null);

    // reset tail node
    tail = new OrderedListNode("TAIL", head, null);

    // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
    head.next = tail;

    // reset size to 0
    theSize = 0;


}
private class OrderedListNode{
    Comparable theItem;
    OrderedListNode next;
    OrderedListNode previous;

    public OrderedListNode(Comparable theItem, OrderedListNode previous, OrderedListNode next){
        this.theItem = theItem;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous=previous;
    }
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";

    OrderedListNode currentNode = head.next;

    while (currentNode != tail)
    {
        s += currentNode.theItem.toString();

        if (currentNode.next != tail)
        {
            s += ", ";
        }

        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: The value of field `theItem` is a `String` for the `head` and `tail` nodes, and an `Integer` for the data nodes, so you're comparing a head/tail node to a data node.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the clean method. It is instantiating string data type nodes and put it into the tail and head. So when remove() was called, while it was iterating/loop through your list of objects when it hits your string typed node, exception was thrown because it was trying to compare int with string.

Anyway I have fixed your problem by reworking part of the code. It's not perfect but it at least no longer hit the issue

Here are the changes.

1st: in the remove method - You will need a break statement otherwise the code can get into infinite loop.

2nd: I have reworked on your Clean method because it contains some logical error. Basically you will want to set things to null or 0 during cleaning and not initializing a new tail and head object for it.

3rd: The add logic is also kind of incorrect, logically wise. I have also reworked on it.

Note: Due to time constraint, I did not really test my own changes so there can be bugs still laying around which is not within the scope of this question.

Just drop a reply message if you find any bugs, I'll find time to have a look again.

```
public class OrderedLinkedList {

    OrderedListNode head = null;
    OrderedListNode tail = null;
    int theSize = 0;

    public boolean add(Comparable obj)
    {
        if(head == null){
            head = new OrderedListNode(obj, head, tail);
        }
        else{
            OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj, /*prev=*/tail, /*next=*/null);
            if (tail == null)
                head.next = newNode;
            else {
                tail.next = newNode;
                // tail.previous = newNode; No need this line. Already set in constructor
            }

            tail = newNode;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(Comparable obj)
    {
        OrderedListNode temp = head;
        boolean elemRemoved = false;
        while(temp != null){
            if(temp.theItem.compareTo(obj) == 0) {
                // dereference this object for garbage collection
                if (temp.previous != null)
                    // Not a head - Head will not have previous
                    temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
                elemRemoved = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        return elemRemoved;
    }
    /**
     *  Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public void clear()
    {
        // reset header node
        head = null;

        // reset tail node
        tail = null;

        // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
        //head.next = tail;

        // reset size to 0
        theSize = 0;


    }
    private class OrderedListNode{
        Comparable theItem;
        OrderedListNode next;
        OrderedListNode previous;

        public OrderedListNode(Comparable theItem, OrderedListNode previous, OrderedListNode next){
            this.theItem = theItem;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous=previous;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";

        OrderedListNode currentNode = head.next;

        while (currentNode != tail)
        {
            s += currentNode.theItem.toString();

            if (currentNode.next != tail)
            {
                s += ", ";
            }

            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        return s;
    }

}


public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedLinkedList one = new OrderedLinkedList();
        one.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i<=20; i=i+2){
            one.add(i);
        }
        boolean removedOK = one.remove(3);
        System.out.println("Attempt 1 : Something was removed => " + removedOK);

        removedOK = one.remove(2);
        System.out.println("Attempt 2: Something was removed => " + removedOK);

        removedOK = one.remove(4);
        System.out.println("Attempt 3: Something was removed => " + removedOK);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey. Just checking to see how you go with the code? Did it fixed your problem or clear any of your doubts? Thanks!